# How to stop line width compression (line length limit)?

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, line-spacing, width, textwidth

I need to generate pure Latex SVG files without any form of document layout or anything, just with a tight bounding box around the generated SVG.

At the moment I am already achieving this using MiKTeX + [DVISVGM](https://dvisvgm.de/) + `\thispagestyle{empty}` at the beginning of my `.tex` file, but my problem is the following:

Once the line/SVG exceeds a certain width, the spaces within the math environments are compressed and shrunk in a very weird way, as you can see in (1). I then deleted a word (to make the line length shorter) but changed nothing else and the formatting was correct, as you can see in (2):

[image]

But it seems like the line also never breaks. Latex just compresses the spaces.

And I am trying to avoid this. This messes up the formatting of my SVG files.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: the lines breaking or not breaking are unrelated to using dvisgm or any information you have given, it is purely a function of the tex markup you have used but not shown.